# Using Reactive Extensions - is this async?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, system.reactive

Trying to convert existing data access code to async and came across Rx because you can't return `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` with a `yield return` in your method body.

I wrote this but not sure its async so pointers gratefully received

```
public class EmployeeRepository : IEmployeeRepository
{
    public IAsyncEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        return Enumerable().ToAsyncEnumerable();
    }

    private IEnumerable<Employee> Enumerable()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES", connection))
            {
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        yield return
                            new Employee()
                                {
                                    Id = ReadField<int>(reader, "Id"),
                                    Name = ReadField<string>(reader, "Name")
                                };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static T ReadField<T>(IDataRecord reader, string fieldName)
    {
        var value = reader[fieldName];
        return value == DBNull.Value ? default(T) : (T)value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "you can't return `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`? Of course you can. Do you mean that your current interface doesn't use that in its method signature? Converting code to async is generally a breaking change, and a pretty major one; you will have to change many interfaces and method signatures. You should even change the names, as it's customary to include the suffix `Async` at the end of asynchronous methods.

Comment: How does the Reactive Framework relate to this question?

Comment: You can't return `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` with `yield return`

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm trying to find a way to do it with yield return and I thought Rx could give me that.

Comment: @Jon - `yield return` only works for `IEnumerable<>`, not `IObservable<>`. It's still synchronous if you're using `yield return`. If you go the Rx route though you could make it async easily, but not `yield return` then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not async. `ToAsyncEnumerable` creates a simple adapter that blocks on every call to `MoveNext`. Returning such an async adapter is bad practice, along the same lines as doing a `Task.Run(() => BlockingMethod())`. It hides an implementation inefficiency from the user which they may have been able to work around in a better way if they knew it existed.

There are no language-integrated yield features for `IAsyncEnumerable`, but it can be emulated. I [have code to do it](http://idcomlog.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#IdComLog.Data/AsyncEnumerableEx.cs), but fair warning this creates a bit of overhead:

```
IAsyncEnumerable<Employee> async = AsyncEnumerableEx.Create<Employee>(
                                                  async (y, cancellationToken) =>
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager
                            .ConnectionStrings["DBConnString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES",
                                            connection))
        {
            using (var reader = await
                                   command.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken))
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken))
                {
                    await y.YieldReturn(new Employee()
                    {
                        Id = ReadField<int>(reader, "Id"),
                        Name = ReadField<string>(reader, "Name")
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If you want to use actual Rx, there is an almost identical `Observable.Create` utility built into it. It will be somewhat more efficient due to cutting out some await overhead.

```
IObservable<Employee> async = Observable.Create<Employee>(
                                                    async (obs, cancellationToken) =>
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager
                            .ConnectionStrings["DBConnString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES",
                                            connection))
        {
            using (var reader = await
                                   command.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken))
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken))
                {
                    obs.OnNext(new Employee()
                    {
                        Id = ReadField<int>(reader, "Id"),
                        Name = ReadField<string>(reader, "Name")
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I have this compiling but it only returns 1 employee not an IEnumerable:

Comment: How are you using it? I don't see any reason for it to return only a single record if there should be more.

Comment: you have to supply a generic type on the Create<T> so what should that be? It has to be a Task<T> right? GetEmployees should return a Task<T> to be async

Comment: Here's a gist. There are 2 items in the DB. It returns only 1. https://gist.github.com/jchannon/6673506

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't test that code. The generic should be `Employee`. IObservable is already async, passing tasks through it is almost always going to be incorrect. Post edited.

Comment: So I should just return `IObservable<Employee>` and not decorate the method with `Task<IObservable<Employee>>`?

Comment: Is this the best way to consume an IObserveable? https://gist.github.com/jchannon/6681836

Comment: That looks like it will work, though it could be shortened to `await repo.GetEmployees().Count()`

Comment: I think I tried that but after the await it looks like its just Employee not IEnumerable which has the Count property

Comment: Is there a way to return an IEnumerable from the IObsever negating the need to Subscribe?

Comment: @Jon, if you are trying to go from `IEnumerable` to `IObservable` you have to stop and question your motives. If you are trying to go from `IEnumerable` to `IObservable` and back to `IEnumerable`, then you are just doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Rx, try something like this:

```
public IObservable<Employee> GetEmployees()
{
    return Observable.Create<Employee>(o =>
        Observable.Using(() => new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["DBConnString"].ConnectionString),
            connection =>
                Observable.Using(() =>
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    return new SqlCommand(
                        @"SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES", connection);
                },
                    command =>
                        Observable.Using(() => command.ExecuteReader(),
                            reader =>
                                Observable.Generate(
                                    0,
                                    x => reader.Read(),
                                    x => x,
                                    x => new Employee()
                                {
                                    Id = ReadField<int>(reader, "Id"),
                                    Name = ReadField<string>(reader, "Name")
                                }, Scheduler.Default)))).Subscribe(o));
}
```

Comment: is this async? I see no async/await and Tas<T> returned

Comment: @Jon - It's async through the `Scheduler.Default`, not thru the new `async`/`await` keywords. There's not a hint of `async` in the OP's original question.

Comment: This is async in the sense that it happens on a background thread, but not in the sense of having any of the scalability a true async op would have.

Comment: @CoryNelson - it's reading serially from a database. How much scalability do you think it can get?

Comment: Quite a bit, but that wasn't my point. This is "pseudo-async" that I mention as bad practice. You can fairly easily rework this sample to use true async.